# input (type=submit) with an icon inside next to Value="Submit"

Tags: input, icons, submit

I cannot solve this because i have many third party content (open licensed) that have some rules that doesnt work with this.

This is the principal code:

```
<input id="submit" class="btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="Comment" tabindex="7" />
```

This show a good button to submit my content. But now i want to include in the "value" a little icon image before the text. The other third party give me this code to include an icon where i want, just putting  tag with the class of the icon that they offer, in this case:

```
<i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i>
```

Normaly, this will work, but in this case is not printed correctly cause is inside "value":

```
<input id="submit" class="btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="<i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i>Comment" tabindex="7" />
```

If you can see the value content, it only read until class= cause there is another quote.

How can I include all the content inside value without this kind of errors?